# Как сравнить значения в div

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<style type="text/css">
        .available-free {
            color: green;
        }

        .available-no {
            color: red;
        }
 </style>

</head>

    <body>

<div class="available-free">3</div>
<div class="available-free">0</div>

<script>

  var free = document.querySelector(".available-free");

  if (free > 0) {
      free.classList.toggle("available-no");
  }

</script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```
var free = document.getElementsByClassName('available-free'),
    item1 = free[0].innerText || free[0].textContent
    item2 = free[1].innerText || free[1].textContent;

if (item1 > item2 ) {
    for(var item of free) {
       item.classList.toggle("available-no");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное )

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайтесь  :)

Answer (score 0):

Используй свойство `textContent`.

Comment: Попробовал, все равно не сравнивает. Если не сложно,  напишите код пожалуйста.